# VSCode file explorer navigation bar?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In RubyMine, PHPStorm (and other JetBrains IDEs I imagine) you can hit <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>⬆</kbd> (or whatever shortcut defined for the action) and browse the files in a project from the point of where the current opened file is situated, they call it the ["Navigation Bar"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#navigate-with-navigation-bar). Is there a feature like this in VSCode that I'm not finding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VSCode, Selecting a breadcrumb in the path displays a dropdown with that level's siblings so you can quickly navigate to other folders and files.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_breadcrumbs

Comment: Finding it to be a little clumsy, but yes this is it. I can hit command + shift + ; and use left and right arrows and then descend into a directory I want. But then I can't go "back up" - i.e., hit the up arrow key and look elsewhere in the file tree.

Answer (score 0):

`CMD` + `SHIFT` + `;`

or

`CMD` + `SHIFT` + `.`